# Поиск соседних станций метро

Tags: php, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Хочу получить поиск ближайших станций метро относительно исходной:
Например, имеем станцию Выхино.

Попытался получить с помощью **http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru**, но не вышло.

Вот пример:

```
$jsonmap = file_get_contents('http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode='.$_REQUEST['metro'].'&kind=metro&format=json');
```

Получаю только информацию об объекте, даже не смог найти примерную реализацию то, что мне необходимо.

Comment: Тут посмотрите, определение ближайшего метро по координатам со стороны сервера
[GitHub пример](https://github.com/chronow/YandexGeocode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотри вот тут
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/metro.closest-docpage/

там конечно на js, но думаю разберешься

UPD:

```js
// Найдем ближайшую к точке (37.588162, 55.733797) станцию метро
// и покажем ее на карте.
var metro = new YMaps.Metro.Closest(
    new YMaps.GeoPoint.(37.588162,55.733797), 
    { results: 1 }
);
YMaps.Events.observe(metro, metro.Events.Load, function () {
    if (this.length()) {
        map.addOverlay(this.get(0));
        map.panTo(this.get(0).getGeoPoint())
    } else {
        alert("Ничего не найдено")
    }
});
YMaps.Events.observe(metro, metro.Events.Fault, function (metro, errorMessage) {
    alert("Произошла ошибка: " + errorMessage)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Параметр `kind` применим только для обратного геокодирования (запроса по координатам). Поэтому в него надо передавать *координаты* станции.

В Вашем кейсе потребуется сделать два запроса к Геокодеру:

1. Определяем координаты станции Выхино

   [https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=метро+Выхино&format=json&results=1](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE+%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE&format=json&results=1)
2. Ищем станции метро, ближайшие к точке из результатов предыдущего запроса

   https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=37.817969,55.715682&kind=metro&format=json&results=3&skip=1

Важный момент: при поиске станций метро рядом с точкой первым результатом будет сама станция Выхино, потому что географически она ближе всего к заданным координатам. Поэтому результаты нужно забирать, начиная со второго, для этого добавлен параметр `skip`.